# Examples of double dual spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, duality-theorems

I am looking for examples on double dual spaces. As I know 
$\ell_p $ is the double dual of $\ell_p$ for $1<p,q<\infty$, $\mathcal L_p $ is the double dual for $\mathcal L_p$ for $1<p,q<\infty$ and $\ell_\infty$ is the double dual of $c_0$, where $c_0$ is the space of sequences of numbers that converge to 0.

I would like to know other examples of the double dual spaces,  especially of non-reflexive spaces.

Comment: An extensive list of interesting Banach spaces and their duals and double duals can be found in Volume 1 of Dunford and Schwartz's tome *Linear Operators*.  By the way, your third example is backwards: $\ell^\infty$ is the double dual of $c_0$, not vice versa.  The double dual of $\ell^\infty$ is... significantly more complicated.

Comment: Also, $\ell_p$ is the double dual of $\ell_p$ for $1<p<\infty$, there is no need for $q$ (or is this what you meant?). Likewise for $\mathcal{L}_p$.

Comment: Though I am by no means an expert, in my experience, the double dual of a non-reflexive space is usually mildly complicated, since taking the dual greatly "expands" a vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is a nice duality between $C(K)$ and $L_1(\mu)$-spaces. The double dual of $C(K)$ is of the form $C(L)$ for some huge compact space $L$. (Actually it is also isometric to $L_\infty(\nu)$  for some huge measure $\nu$.) The second dual of $L_1(\mu)$ is also of the form $L_1(\nu)$. However people rarely think of duals/biduals of these spaces like that. If $K$ is a [scattered](http://planetmath.org/scatteredspace) compact space, then $C(K)^*$ is nice: it is $\ell_1(K)$, so that $C(K)^{**} = \ell_\infty(K)$. This property characterises scattered compact spaces.
- Another good example of a bidual space is $\mathscr{K}(\ell_p)^{**} = \mathscr{B}(\ell_p)$ for $p\in (1,\infty)$. In other words, bounded operators on $\ell_p$ are the second dual of the space compact operators on $\ell_p$. This extends to some more general Banach spaces.
- The second dual can add very little; all quasi-reflexive spaces are good examples. Historically the first example is due to James ([the James space](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~schlump/lecture20and21.pdf)). It is a certain sequence space whose dual is also a sequence space; actually $J^{**} = \mbox{span}\{J, \mathbf{1}\}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the constant sequence.

Comment: What is "huge" compact space?

Comment: @C.Ding, it is not a mathematical term... You may say humongous if you wish.