# An example of second conjugate

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

we know that $X$ is a normed vector space and $X'$ is the conjugate of $X$ (set of linear bounded functional defined on $X$) and $X''$ is the second conjugate of $X$ (i.e. the set of of linear bounded functional on $X'$).

As example... $X$ could be set of continous function on a compact interval $I$ while an element of $X'$ could be an integral operator what could be an example of instance belonging to $X''$?

Comment: Because of the canonical embedding $X\to X''$, we can regard elements of $X''$ as some kind of '*generalized functions*'. Perhaps we get a famous function space, like $L_1(I)$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1033024/17929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main objects in $X''$ are the evaluation maps: $(T_x)(f)=f(x)$ where $x \in X$. (My $T$ is called the canonical embedding of $X$ into $X''$.) If $X$ is reflexive (which is true in many important examples, such as $L^p$ spaces for $1<p<\infty$), then this is everything in $X''$.

Otherwise $X''$ contains additional objects. It may or may not be easy to see what these objects look like. @TomekKanla's answer deals with the case $X=C[0,1]$. A nastier case is the case $X=L^1([0,1])$. Here, under the axiom of choice it is possible to prove that there exist members of $(L^1)''=(L^\infty)'$ which are not given by integration against an $L^1$ function. Instead they are given by integration against so-called "finitely additive measures". In the context of the Lebesgue measure, such a thing has never been constructed, and probably can never be constructed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your last sentence? I don't quite get what you mean by that.

Comment: @TomekKania The "never been constructed" thing should be clear, I think. The "can never be constructed" thing has to do with a certain level of "arbitrary choice" that is required in the construction. When we build the Lebesgue measure, we can start from the length of rational intervals--a countable set--and extend essentially by "continuity". (More or less; there are some issues with null sets in the way, but hopefully you get the idea.)

Comment: @TomekKania But finitely additive measures are not at all continuous, which means you have to actually *define* all of these values on this huge set of subsets of the line. And you have to define them in an "inconsistent" manner, so that you don't "accidentally get countable additivity". The axiom of choice does this for us in the proof, but the axiom of choice is fundamentally nonconstructive.

Comment: Just a curiosity... your "evaluation map" is the same as the "natural map"? because maybe it is my impression... but it looks different the definition i have on my book.

Comment: @Lukkio Can you write your definition? I've seen it written like that or like $(T(x))(f)=f(x)$ (which is a bit clearer).

Comment: From my book (Goldberg, unbounded linear operator theory and applications) def 1.6.8. "The natural map, denoted by $J_X$, of normed linear space $X$ into its second conjugate space $X''$ (the banach space of bounded linear functionals on $X'$ is defined by $(J_X x)x' = x'x \;\;,\;\; x' \in X'$. If the range of $J_X$ is all of $X''$ then $X$ is called reflexive.

Comment: It looks like is the bounded linear functional fixed, instead in your definition is the element of $X$ that is being fixed.

Comment: @Lukkio The definitions are the same, just the notation is slightly different. The point is that for each $x \in X$, you can define a linear functional on $X'$ which is given by evaluating the given member of $X'$ at $x$. My $T$, or your $J_X$, is really a function of two variables, one in $X$, one in $X'$. When we specify both, we get a scalar. When we specify only the $X$ variable, we get a member of $X''$. When we specify only the $X'$ variable, we get a member of $X'$.

Comment: @Ian If it is a function of two variable why it is specified a domain? I have specified that the domain is $X$. I'm getting confused now...

Comment: @Lukkio What's going on here is called currying in the computer science community. Here you have a function of two variables, and when you hold one of the variables constant, what you get is a function of one variable. So this means that if you have $J : X \times X' \to \mathbb{R}$, if you specify the first argument to be $x$, you get a function $K : X' \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $K(f)=J(x,f)$. Because this function is actually bounded and linear in this context, this is then a member of $X''$. So given a member of $X$, you get a member of $X''$, *which is itself a function*.

Comment: @Lukkio (Cont.) Computer scientists call this new function (which only takes one variable) a curried function.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. One uses AC to show that functionals on $L_\infty$ can be abstractly represented as finitely additive measures. This result is indeed very much existential. The last sentence introduces unnecessary confusion, that is my point. Also, I don't think that your answer addresses OP's question.

Comment: @TomekKania The first paragraph is the main point; in the cases with which I am familiar, the members of $X''$ which are not given by the canonical embedding are hard to grasp, except when $X$ is not complete.

Comment: @Ian, not always. In the case of $C[0,1]$ which was the main concern of OP's question they are easy to point out. Any bounded Borel function does the job.

Comment: @TomekKania I think we read the question differently. To me the question was "how do I look at $X''$ in general? Maybe the example where $X=C[0,1]$ would be illuminating". But you're right about that case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=C[0,1]$. Then any bounded Borel function $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ defines an element of $C[0,1]^{**}$ via

$$\langle f, \mu \rangle = \int\limits_{[0,1]} f(t)\,\mu({\rm d }t)\qquad (\mu \in C[0,1]^*).$$

where we identify $C[0,1]^*$ with the space of all regular Borel measures on $[0,1]$ using the Riesz representation theorem.

However the second dual of $C[0,1]$ is much larger than just the set of bounded Borel functions. It can be identified with the space $L_\infty(\mu)$ for some silly measure $\mu$ that is not even $\sigma$-finite.

(I write $X^*$ instead of $X^\prime$.)